# label and dash component side by side

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using Dash. One of the thing I want to do is have a label and slider side by side. The following code render this. What can I do the the code so that the slider label and the slider shows up side by side. Thanks.

[image]

```
                                    html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.Label("First Slider"),
                                        dcc.RangeSlider(
                                            id="my-range-slider",
                                            # label="Slider 1",
                                            min=0,
                                            step=0.01,
                                            max=1,
                                            value=[0.2, 0.8],
                                            marks={0: "0", 1: "1"},
                                            allowCross=False,
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                    className="rows",
                                ),
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.Label("Second Slider"),
                                        dcc.RangeSlider(
                                            id="my-range-slider1",
                                            # label="Slider 1",
                                            min=0,
                                            step=0.01,
                                            max=1,
                                            value=[0.2, 0.8],
                                            marks={0: "0", 1: "1"},
                                            allowCross=False,
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                    className="rows",
                                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will get that done easily. Make each of the containing divs have `style=dict(display='flex')`, and just make sure there's enough horizontal room.