# html components stacks instead of columns using dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash and have run into a problem when trying to setup my application.
I want to plot two text boxes side by side. One should take up 1/3 width of the screen and the other should use the remaining 2/3. However, when I run my app, the boxes are on top of each other:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

content = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([html.H4('Simulation time', className='card-title')], className='four columns', style=dict(display='flex')),
        html.Div([html.H4('Simulation results', className='card-title')], className='eight columns', style=dict(display='flex'))
    ], className='row', style=dict(display='flex'))
], style=dict(display='flex'))

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Any help is appreaciate.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754626/layout-and-dropdown-menu-in-dash-python/55755387#55755387) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515531/label-and-dash-component-side-by-side/63515569#63515569).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [label and dash component side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515531/label-and-dash-component-side-by-side)

Comment: No unfortunately not, adding style=dict(display='flex') to each Div does not make them stand side by side. They are still stacker. I have updated my question to reflect what I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked fine when I ran it without changes. The text appeared side by side. I've updated it to give the widths you're looking for.

```py
content = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([html.H4('Simulation time', className='card-title')], className='four columns', style=dict(width='33%')),
        html.Div([html.H4('Simulation results', className='card-title')], className='eight columns', style=dict(width='66%'))
    ], className='row', style=dict(display='flex', width='100%'))
], style=dict(display='flex'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. Yes, it also worked for me when I restarted my computer. Why there was a problem before, I do not know. Hence, I have marked your solution as an answer.